# Got "Unknown select target" error when running PostgreSQL entry id in MindsDB SQL Editor

Tags: sql, postgresql, mindsdb

I am trying to run a SQL query from MindsDB SQL Editor and partition the data  by specific entry id from a PostgreSQL table, but I got the below error:

```
Unknown select target <class 'mindsdb_sql.parser.ast.select.operation.WindowFunction'>
```

Example of the query:

```sql
 SELECT pid, pname,  docid, ptemp, avg(ptemp) OVER (PARTITION BY docid) FROM postgresql_integration.patients_data;
```

I have tried reading the documentation of MindsDB but still no answer for this particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MindsDB's database engine is MySQL, but you can still run native SQL queries depending on your connected database, in your case PostgreSQL. To be able to do this you will need to wrap up the native query inside the ***SELECT FROM integration_name()*** statement. In your example as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM postgresql_integration(
 SELECT pid, pname,  docid, ptemp, avg(ptemp) OVER (PARTITION BY docid) FROM patients_data
);
```

For more info, you can check out the [Native query documentation](https://docs.mindsdb.com/sql/native-queries).